# apache ignite cumpute service with affinity

Tags: java, microservices, distributed, ignite

I would like to run a service/compute jub on ignite using a service but run the job where the data is.

from the client I will either call a compute or service proxy but need the service to run near the cache data.

I noticed you can use a service from a compute job:

```
compute.run(new IgniteRunnable() {
  @ServiceResource(serviceName = "myCounterService");
  private MyCounterService counterSvc;
```

If I deploy the service on every node in the cluster can I use compute with near cach to do this?

```
 compute.affinityRun(CACHE_NAME, key, () -> { 
      // call my servie here...
```

maybe there is a way to directly call a service proxy with affinity to avoid using comupte?

p.s. the reason is the service preduce more cache data and I would like to avoid transferring large data between nodes and clients back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell Ignite, which service instance to use, based on the argument of the method being called.

Services are good when you need to store some state in them. Otherwise compute jobs are just as effective. Moreover, compute jobs are used internally to call services' methods.

So, if you don't have any state, then just use the compute jobs. Otherwise you can try injecting needed resources into compute jobs: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/resource-injection

Comment: My main concern is to pass a large comupte code each time I have a new object, with service I can deploy the class with the server node and call it remotely from the client using a proxy. I will have to somehow combine comupte and service...

Comment: @Gadi actually, code won't be sent over network every time. It will be deployed only once, and the same class will be used during consecutive calls. Only data will be sent.

Comment: is this true for a compute job that holds a new key each time? my plan is to push the new cache entry via the cache API and then run the compute job on this key -> generate more cache objects directly on the server. Do you have a code example for this?

Comment: @Gadi, yes, the same class will be used each time. Only data will change. You can find a code example of affinityRun in the documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#section-collocating-compute-with-data

Comment: this only works for primitives, if you need a POJO then you need to pre deploy them on the server anyway. Ignite fail to serialise my compute code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Affinity key based deployment](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-grid#section-affinity-key-based-deployment)

Comment: no, this is not what I want. I want all nodes to contain the service and only the one that is near the data to accept the job